# What can I call my every day customs?

Tags: planets

I am making a story that is set in the 22nd century and people now inhabit Jupiter instead of Earth. There is a lot of newer technology out now and i need help on what to call them. Communication devices, transportation and broadcasting and even artificial mechanical limbs, what are some names I can identify them with? Help please.

Comment: I am respectfully confused as to how cell phones, cars, and TVs can be called "newer technology" in the 2100s, and why they would need dystopian rebranding. You may want to clarify your question.

Comment: If you do not want to lose your readers - unless you are a linguist for example and you want to create a new language - call things by the names that people understand. Don't go too deep into your world and become absorbed into it. There are a number of examples when books with this kind of thing worked, but most of the time it worked in spite of it. Also language doesn't change that quickly

Comment: Hi bbybyzy, and welcome to Worldbuilding and Stack Exchange! I think this question falls outside of Worldbuilding's scope, as it is inherently about telling a story (what to call a particular device) rather than building a world (for example: how does this device work). Any names anyone comes up with will also be very hard to judge objectively on how well they answer the question, hence this is opinion-based. Consequently, I'm voting to put this on hold.

Comment: I see you have at least one other question which has also been closed as off topic; you may want to familiarize yourself with our scope before posting further, as having too many poorly received question can severely limit your ability to ask further questions on the site. I strongly recommend reviewing the [help] (particularly the section on asking questions) and, now that you have the required 5 rep, that you consider using our [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29) to get early feedback on your questions before posting them on the main site.

Comment: I agree with the feedback you've already been given, that this question may not be a good fit, here. One bit that I'd like to echo, though, is what @Raditz_35 said about picking understandable names. The world of Mad Max, for example, often gives the *appearance* of an evolved (devolved?) language while keeping it understandable. "I am leg-broke!" is easily understood even without additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean, if you want an oppressive government You could name them all as more functional descriptions, that make it seem that the society views the people as tools.

Prosthetic limbs become human repair unit, cell phones are worker intercom, television is citizens intelligence portal.

Or you could show the authority through the names, such as calling a car, a permitted private transport.